# Delphi XE7 - Make PNG image transparent inside Form

Tags: image, delphi, transparency

I set the Form Color to : clFichsia and TransparentColor: True and TransparentColorValue to : clFuchsia.
I need to remove the clFuchsia color from the Form.
Normally the image is transparent but when i load it in the application
the color of the Form doesn't disappear.

How my application looks like: [image: http://i.imgur.com/ivtm6ld.png]

Comment: PNGs use partial transparency. Why are you setting transparent properties?

Comment: What type of file should i use?

Comment: No. PNGs are fine. You just need to stop setting those transparent properties. A plain TImage with default props should do what you need.

Comment: But i need to be shown only the cloud and replace the form. As fas as the borders of the application is concerned, ill just remove them from the Form properties.

Comment: How about you edit the question to state what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different ways to handle transparency:

1) the old simplified (Windows/Delphi) way, where a specific RGB color is made transparent. This method does not allow any partial transparency (opacity is either 0% or 100%).

2) the "new" way, where you use an image with an alpha-channel, e.g. a PNG image. Each pixel has an opacity value in addition to the RGB value, which allows partial transparency (e.g. for anti-aliasing).

You are mixing those two methods. You load a PNG image with an alpha channel (method 2), but then you also set a transparent color (method 1). And the reason it looks that bad, is because the "fuchsia" RGB value in your image is not exactly the same everywhere.